# d2i_X509 collapses, bad certificate format?

Tags: c, linux, openssl

i've created a pair of keys and a self-signed certificate.
the keys are surrounded with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and the certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

i have this line:

```
X509 *x509_certificate = d2i_X509(NULL, &cert_ptr, cert_size)
```

where cert_ptr points to a buffer of unsigned chars.
So, I chaged my certificate by hex editor from ascii to Hex, just to put it inside the buffer {0xAA, 0xBB...} for example..
But it seems that i'm doing someting wrong, because d2i_X509 collapses.

thanks

Comment: " So, I chaged my certificate by hex editor from ascii to Hex" - why have you done it?

Comment: Id2i_X509 gets as a param a pointer to a buffer of hex bytes..

Comment: bytes are just bytes.  They do not have any intrinsic base.

Comment: What does *"d2i_X509 collapses"* mean? Also, I believe you need to call `X509_free` on the pointer returned by `d2i_X509`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in C#.

Passing the certificate without the header and footer line and decoding the content from Base64 helped to parse the Cert.

Comment: thanks! that helped!